# How to determine what strength of electromagnet is needed

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I have a project where I want to put an electromagnet on a rail system that can move on a plane. Above the electromagnet I will have a plywood board with some metal circles on top of it. I want to be able to move said circles, which will weigh and estimated half pound and will have a 0.25" diameter, with the electromagnet, which I estimate will be no more than 0.5" inches below the bottom of the circles.

The only issue is that I have no clue what strength of electromagnet I need to buy on amazon, I'd prefer to buy the smallest possible one. I know distance heavily affects magnetic strength but aside from that I'm not really sure how to go about calculating it. Does the volume of the metal matter? Any advice on how to do this math or simply the answer to my question would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: This will depend largely on the friction between the magnet rings and the plywood. Plywood is pretty rough, so it's not a great choice for a low-friction surface

Comment: I can definitely make the surface slicker